# Set value for the data-quantity attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to get the value using id. But I want to change the value of data-quantity dynamically. The html is below:

```
<div class="quantity" id="iddq" data-quantity="0/1"></div>
```

To get the value I use the below line of code:

```
var data = $('#iddq').data('quantity');
```

How to set new value using jquery or javascript?

If I use the below code I am not able to change the value.

```
document.getElementbyId("5").setAttribute('data-quantity',1/5);
```

Comment: `$('#iddq').data('quantity', newvalue)`

Answer (score 0):

To set the data value, you can use the setter version of [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1) which takes 2 parameters, the key and the new value

```
$('#iddq').data('quantity', newvalue);
```

Note: This will not update the attribute value as jQuery's `data` api uses an internal storage for data.

If you really want to change the attribute value, use the getter and setter version of `.attr()` like

```
var data = $('#iddq').attr('data-quantity');
$('#iddq').attr('data-quantity', newvalue);
```

Comment: Ya i need to change the value dynamically based on a condition. So I will try the getter and setter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need use [`.data( key, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

> value: The new data value; this can be any Javascript type except undefined.

*Code*

```
$('#iddq').data('quantity', newvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works too.

```
$('#iddq').attr('data-quantity', newvalue);
```